# Prevent instantiation of class in library

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I derive from a class of a NuGet package, let's call it `BaseClass`. The class is concrete, public and has a public constructor. It is not partial, which is why I need to derive from it to extend it, let's call that `DerivedClass`.

I want to work with a derived class due to several reasons that make developing and maintaining easier, like in code first entity framework, ...

I want to prevent instantiation of the `BaseClass` and enforce using the `DerivedClass`. The class is one of many I use from that package. The class is used heavily inside the lib which is fine. So I can't replace it, but I have to extend it by methods and properties myself.

`BaseClass` will be available for future use, but not for creating a new instance, besides the call of the parent constructor inside of `DerivedClass`.

I know this is neither an ideal scenario nor architecture, but we are pretty much bound here due to our third-party dependencies and implementations.

I also tried to look into AoP frameworks, but couldn't really find something, like e.g. postsharp, but I can't add the necessary attributes at design time, only at runtime which renders tools on IL level useless for me.

Comment: You can write a Roslyn analyser which raises a warning if it sees you instantiating a `BaseClass`?

Comment: *"It is not partial"* - This would only matter if the package included the source code rather than an assembly, in which case you could make it abstract with `abstract partial class BaseClass { }`. Once a class is compiled to an assembly, there's no "partial" characteristic.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why not have `DerivedClass` store the `BaseClass` as a private readonly field? That way you control its initialization within the class, its use will be only within that class, and then only `DerivedClass` to be exposed? Things like extensions and partial classes are great tools, but in some cases its better to just use something as a dependency. You should give some sample code as its a bit unclear what exactly is happening here. A nuget library is someone else's library, its going to be hard to force it to be essentially `abstract` if it isn't abstract

Comment: If `BaseClass` does not need be accessible by users of your library, could you wrap your library in another that has different accessible features?